# Where to include '$' in equation?

Tags: math-mode, errors

This code displays error of including `$` in some places. Please help

```
\begin{equation} 
  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{im\theta}d\theta = \begin{cases}
                                            0, & \text{if m\neq 0},\\
                                            2\pi, & \text{if m=0}.
                                          \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: It's because you've got the maths within `\text{}`, so for example `\neq` must be in math mode, but you have `\text{if m\neq 0}`, better would be `\text{if $m\neq 0$}` or `\text{if } m \neq 0` or something like that

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there.  Inside `\text` you must include mathematical expressions into `$...$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{im\theta}d\theta = \begin{cases}
                                            0, & \text{if $m\neq 0$},\\
                                            2\pi, & \text{if $m=0$}.
                                          \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By personal preference I would typeset it like below.  I define a macro for the differential d which adds some spacing before and use the `cases*` environment from the `mathtools` package which wraps the second column into `\text` automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!d}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{im\theta} \diff\theta =
  \begin{cases*}
    0    & if $m\neq 0$, \\
    2\pi & if $m=0$.
  \end{cases*}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]